# Date Parameter as String C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq on my C# code:

```
var model = await _context.Mfhargapasars.Select(s => new { 
            HPCode = s.Mfhpcode,
            HPDate = s.Mfhpdate.ToShortDateString(),
            HPType = s.Mfhptype,
            HPPrice = s.Mfhpprice
        }).Where(x => x.HPCode == id && x.HPDate == tgl).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

The `tgl` parameter also has been converted to ShortDateString.
But when I tried to execute the query above. It gaves me an error like:

`InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Mfhp>() .Where(m => m.Mfhpcode == __id_0 && m.Mfhpdate.ToShortDateString() == __tgl_1)' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'System.DateTime.ToShortDateString' failed.`

When I debug The `tgl` parameter, the value is: `31/01/2023`.

Please advice.
Thank you.

Comment: The LINQ to Entities provider, as used by EF, translates your LINQ code to SQL code to be executed against the database. The fact that some C# code is valid LINQ doesn't mean that it can be converted to SQL and, as the error message is telling you, `ToShortDateString` can't. You might try `ToString` and specify the format, although I'm not 100% sure that that will work either. If not, there may be a EF extension that will do the job. The real question is why you've got dates stored as text in the database in the first place? It's just an absolutely dumb thing to do. Maybe someone else did it.

Comment: Why do you want this? Formatting is best left to the UI, not the data access code. All UI stacks and report engines allow styling and formatting eg, through format parameters or data binding. Right now you're trying to use the user's current collation, which may or may *not* be the one you really want. If you want to export the data for example, you need ISO8601 dates, not localized dates

Comment: If `Mfhpdate` is a date, *don't* convert it to string. Convert `tgl` back into a date or use the original date. Use `thatDate.Date` if you need only the date part.

Answer (score 0):

1. Move 'Where' method ahead of 'Select'. Tgl should be DateTime. A chance it can help without the second action.
2. Use 'ToString()' as suggested. It will be properly translated to SQL:

   ```
    var model = await _context.Mfhargapasars
        .Where(x => x.HPCode == id && x.HPDate == tgl)
        .Select(s => new { 
            HPCode = s.Mfhpcode,
            HPDate = s.Mfhpdate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), // use the date format you need
            HPType = s.Mfhptype,
            HPPrice = s.Mfhpprice
        }).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
   ```

It looks strange what ToShortDateString cann't be translated.

P. S. Verified, it works. ToShortDateString works as expected. At least with EF MS SQL Server.

Comment: It's not strange. There's no such function in SQL and the actual short date format is different in every culture and *none* (except the US) puts the month in front. When exporting data the safe option is YYYY-MM-DD, not the US-only format. LINQ-to-EF translates LINQ queries into SQL, it doesn't run them on the client

Comment: I doubt `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` would work either. Different databases have different format functions and specify the format in different ways

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Why ToShortDateString cann't be converted to SQL? "ToShortDateString method is identical to calling the DateTime.ToString(String) method with "d" as the format parameter." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring?view=net-7.0

Comment: Which has no equivalent in SQL, and a pattern that depends on the culture

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "I doubt..." - I guess EF should consider the appropriate format. It works, I use it.